# Angular test fails when checking if nested *ngIf element exists

Tags: angular, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

I have the following chuck of HTML which checks if the object configService.config$.footerLinks exists and if it does it creates a UL element. Inside that there are further checks for strings inside the object which correspond to it's respective LI elements.

```
    <ul id="footer-links" *ngIf="(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks">
      <li id="footer-link-manual" *ngIf="(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks.manual">
        <a href="{{(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks.manual}}" target="_blank">Manual</a>
      </li>
      <li  id="footer-link-terms-and-conditions" *ngIf="(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks.termsAndConditions">
        <a href="{{(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks.termsAndConditions}}" target="_blank">Terms</a>
      </li>
      <li  id="footer-link-privacy-policy" *ngIf="(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks.privacyPolicy">
        <a href="{{(configService.config$ | async)?.footerLinks.privacyPolicy}}" target="_blank">Pricacy</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I have written the following test file with two tests

```
// imports, providers & schemas
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Config } from '@app/shared/models/config';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// services
import { ConfigService } from '@app/shared/services/config.service';

// component page
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';

class FakeConfigService {
  configSubject = new Subject<Config>();
  config$: Observable<Config>;
  constructor() {
    this.config$ = this.configSubject.asObservable();
  }
}

fdescribe('footer-component', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>;
  let fakeConfigService: FakeConfigService;  

  beforeEach(() => {

    fakeConfigService = new FakeConfigService();    

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: ConfigService, useValue: fakeConfigService },        
      ],
      declarations: [ FooterComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
    }).overrideComponent(FooterComponent, {
      set: { changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default }
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);    
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fakeConfigService.configSubject.unsubscribe();
  });


  it('Should show the footer links if a footer link is present', () => {
    const configSubject: Config = {
      allowedGoogleDomains: ['something.com'],
      footerLinks: {
        manual: 'something.com/manual',
        termsAndConditions: 'something.com/termsAndConditions',
        privacyPolicy: 'something.com/privacyPolicy'
      }
    };

    fakeConfigService.configSubject.next(configSubject);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const footerLinks = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#footer-links'));

    expect(footerLinks).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('Should show the footer manual link if a footer manual link is present', () => {
    const configSubject: Config = {
      allowedGoogleDomains: ['something.com'],
      footerLinks: {
        manual: 'something.com/manual',
      }
    };

    fakeConfigService.configSubject.next(configSubject);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const footerLinkManual = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#footer-link-manual'));

    expect(footerLinkManual).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The first test first if the UL is created once you populate configService.config$.footerlinks and that passes just fine.

The second one which tests if the LI containing the link for the manual fails. When I console.log the nativeElement for fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#footer-links')) it comes up with this

```
LOG LOG: <ul _ngcontent-a-c1="" id="footer-links"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--></ul>
```

So for whatever reason the test populates the UL but does not populate the LI connected to configService.config$.footerlinks.manual even though they are populated by the same object. Any clues why this is happening?

Should mention that I also tried using fakeAsync/tick() and async/fixture.whenStable and I get the same results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you use `async` pipes then you should use `tick()` in your tests to move time forward. https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick

Comment: I have tried that and unfortunately I still get the same results. I tried it with fixture.whenStable() as well but to no avail.

Comment: not an answer to your question but you should probably just have a single async pipe like `*ngIf="configService.config$ | async as config"` wrapping everything else and then you can just access `config` as a variable.. each of those async pipes is a separate subscription which is bad for performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you have `| async` in your template, it creates a new subscription to the observable. So, if your real observable for example is an HTTP observable, that will send 7 HTTP requests to get the config.

In your test, when you emit from your subject and detect the changes, then the first ngIf condition becomes true, and the ones inside are then evaluated. But since the subject has emitted before, they evaluate to false.

You really need to avoid having many subscriptions in your template. The code should, at least, be changed to

```
<ng-container *ngIf="configService.config$ | async as config>
  <ul id="footer-links" *ngIf="config.footerLinks">
      <li id="footer-link-manual" *ngIf="config.footerLinks.manual">
        <a [href]="config.footerLinks.manual" target="_blank">Manual</a>
      </li>
      <li  id="footer-link-terms-and-conditions" *ngIf="config.footerLinks.termsAndConditions">
        <a [href]="config.footerLinks.termsAndConditions" target="_blank">Terms</a>
      </li>
      <li  id="footer-link-privacy-policy" *ngIf="config.footerLinks.privacyPolicy">
        <a [href]="config.footerLinks.privacyPolicy" target="_blank">Pricacy</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

You should also learn about the smart/dumb pattern to avoid that kind of issue and make your code more testable.

And the template should really not access anything from a service directly. Encapsulat that in your component.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much for your help and advice kind sir!